# The criterion for a real series to be convergent

Tags: real-analysis

I was told that a series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ of real numbers is convergent if and only if $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t.
$$n\geq N\Rightarrow|\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k|<\epsilon.$$
Now I want to prove this claim, and it occurs to me that the series is convergent if and only if $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t.
$$m\geq n\geq N\Rightarrow|\sum_{k=n}^m a_k|<\epsilon.$$
This is the so-called Cauchy criterion. But what's next? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Your first inequality is just the definition of the limit for the sequence of partial sums.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write $ \sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty} a_n$ before knowing that the series is convergent. So the first criterion for convergence is not valid. It is, in fact, a meaningless statement. The other criterion  you have written is correct.

Comment: What if the author means that it's convergent and has the sum $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty} a_n$?

Comment: @Steve If the sum from $n$ to $\infty$ is convergent then automatically the sum from $1$ to $\infty$ is also convergent.